# will ubuntu 15 download to a faulty ubuntu 14 running next to a windows 10 install?

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to install an earlier ubuntu on a windows 8 laptop next to windows.  I thought it was 14.  It didn't install correctly so it wouldn't run.  I just upgraded to windows 10 on the laptop.  What can I do to install the new version of ubuntu over the faulty version?  If I download the new version will it over-write the faulty?  I'm not very savvy so it needs to be simple.

Comment: It will, if you tell it to. I strongly suggest looking at a couple of installation guides before reinstalling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: If you have a problem you need to give more information. Could be anything from a bad download to a bad burn to incompatible hardware. You description "it wouldn't run" does not say much and it is impossible to give more specific advice.

Comment: If you are given a choice where to install the new ubuntu version, could I first download the new version using windows 10, which i installed using 8.  Then would I be given the choice where to install the new version.  This would solve the booting from usb problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you boot the disk, you will see an option for where to install the new ubuntu version.  It will present you with an option for where you'd like to install and inform you on what will happen.  One of the options will be to over-write the ubuntu partition, another will be to over-write the windows partition, and lastly it may present you an option to upgrade the ubuntu partition.

choose wisely. :)

Comment: i tried downloading for a usb boot, but the computer isn't evidently set up to do that.  it acted as if the usb wasn't there, and just said that something was missing for ubuntu to run.  if i downloaded directly the new version on windows 10, is there a way to install it over the faulty version of ubuntu?  i appreciate the help.  i'm 70 and this is real confusing and drives me nutty.

Comment: It may have something to do with a secure-boot setting in your system bios.  (granted if this is disabled your windows 10 image most likely won't boot.)  

it may also simply be a bios setting in the boot order which needs to have the usb drive "turned on"/"added"  

to check either of these two, try F10, or Delete, or F2, or F12  as your computer boots.. (or it may even tell you on boot briefly (usually near the bottom right of the screen) which button to press to enter setup/or settings)

Comment: I tried all these, even though i didn't have any idea what i was doing.  nothing seemed to work.  If i downloaded ubuntu directly to the laptop on windows 10, i assume that i could choose to run the new working version next to windows 10, and i would probably still have the non-working version still on the other partition.  Is there a way to wipe the non-working ubuntu off the drive?

Comment: you could use the live cd to reformat the old ubuntu partition with gparted.  which will wipe it off the drive.

Comment: laptop has no cd-I downloaded a usb but it wouldn't run-the laptop doesn't appear to have the choice to start up from a laptop-I don't understand with gparted-sorry I'm so computer unsavvy

Comment: what is the laptop make and model?

Comment: acer aspire E1-522-5659

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne522 <-- reading here

Comment: it looks like everything worked in 12.04 LTS,  i would assume 14.04.3 also will work.

Comment: avoid the odd year releases, they're usually the testing branch and break things.  (ie. 09,11,13,15,17,etcetc)

Comment: after 1st ubuntu install it wouldn't boot.  got msg. the application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.  also msg. file: ubuntu/winboot\wabildr.mbc  that file apparently was not installed during download-since the computer doesn't appear to be able to boot from a usb, could I download the new version of ubuntu using windows 10, then have a choice to completely install new ubuntu over the old faulty ubuntu?

Comment: thanks much for all your bother, i'm disabled and have problems dealing with the confusion, so i'm very helpless with this